# How we can solve this :$y'(x)=\frac{y^3(x)}{y(x)+x}$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have tried to get the solution of this ODE : $\displaystyle y'(x)=\frac{y^3(x)}{y(x)+x}$ using variable change $y=zx$  ,but i don't succeed to solve it , it's seems to me that it's solution should include error function . Then my question here is : How we can solve it ?

Comment: you may consider to solve $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{y+x}{y^3}$ which is linear

Answer (score 1):

write your equation in the form
$$-y(x)^3+(x+y(x))*y'(x)=0$$
now compute an integrating factor
$$-y^3\frac{d \mu(y)}{dy}-3y^2\mu(y)=\mu(y)$$
and
$$\frac{\frac{\partial\mu(y)}{\partial (y)}}{\mu(y)}=\frac{-3y^2-1}{y^3}$$
which gives
$$\mu(y)=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2y^2}}}{y^3}$$
and then
$$-e^{\frac{1}{2y(x)^2}}+\frac{\left(e^{\frac{1}{2y(x)^2}}(x+y(x)\right)\frac{dy(x)}{dx}}{y(x)^3}=0$$
So fare on this evening. the rest Comes tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'(x)=\frac{y^3(x)}{y(x)+x}$$
Considering $x'$ rather than $y'$
$$y'(x)(y+x)=y^3$$
$$(y+x)=y^3x'$$
$$x'=\frac {(y+x)}{y^3}$$
$$x'-\frac {x}{y^3}=\frac 1 {y^2}$$
Then try to integrate
$$\ln(x)=\int \frac {dy}{y^3}=\frac {-1}{2y^2}+K \implies x=Ke^{\frac {-1}{2y^2}}$$
$$K'e^{\frac {-1}{2y^2}}=\frac 1 {y^2} \implies K=C+\int \frac 1 {y^2} e^{\frac {1}{2y^2}} dy$$
$$x=Ce^{\frac {-1}{2y^2}}+e^{\frac {-1}{2y^2}}\int \frac {e^{\frac {1}{2y^2}}} {y^2}  dy$$
The last integral is not easy to evaluate though
$$........$$